# How can i send a push notification to the user using FCM from server?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have a https.onCall function in my cloud function. I want to send the user a push notification when the function is called from the user. Firebase documentation is not helping me.

```
exports.bookRoom = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { 

  if (context.auth.token.teacher === true || context.auth.token.admin === true) {

    // here i want to send notification to the client
  }
});
```